# Remove column name after get data

Tags: flutter

So when I get some string data from database I'm using this method

```
 var res = "";
  Future<void> cetak(String query) async {
    var req = await SqlConn.readData(query);
    setState(() {
      res = req;
    });
  }
```

then im using method `cetak()` like this

```
 cetak("SELECT CUST_NAME FROM ts_custxm WHERE CUST_CODE = '$custCode'");
```

But when im trying to display the res using `Text(res)`
it show `[{"CUST_NAME":"MY NAME"}]`

any idea how to make `res` only show `MY NAME` without show its column name?

Comment: I untagged SQL Server because the solution has nothing to do with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting result of a query in **res** variable. As a result of a query is an array of objects.

in your case : **[{"CUST_NAME":"MY NAME"}]**

so get **MY NAME** you should use **res[0]["CUST_NAME"].toString()**.

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert by `jsonDecode()` or `json.decode()`:

```
var req = jsonDecode(req)
setState(() {
    res = req;
});
```

and then access to your data by:

```
res[0]["CUST_NAME"].toString()
```

Comment: I'm doing what you suggest, but when im run the code, its show nothing and in the debug console its show **Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'**